# C++ code/XML generation tools

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, code-generation

I'm not sure what exactly the right term is, kind of like ORM using XML as the data store. Are there any decent tools which will autogenerate C++ classes (including data and serialization/deserialization) based on an XML schema? Or will create XML-sync code and schema based on a C++ class definition?

TinyXML is great but it's so old-school to spend all that time writing code to load/save XML data to classes. I've seen similar tools focused on SOAP/WSDL, but they generated all kinds of other code on top of the basics.

Any good open-source libraries out there?

Comment: Auto-generating C++ classes based on an XML schema is not a good idea in my experience, especially if the schema is large and/or subject to change. Every time the schema changes you have to regenerate all of the classes, which typically entails a full rebuild of the remainder of your system.

Comment: Better I have to rebuild than my code is wrong. And time to rebuild is better than days writing and testing ultra-dull XML (de)serialization code.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've seen that attempts to do this is [CodeSynthesisXSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/).

Comment: We tried this and about 5 other products, this was the winner.
Good support too.

Comment: Greg doesn't mention which other products that he and his collaborators tried, but a number of other possibilities are offered in response to [XML Schema to C++ Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/445905/1497596).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an open source and commercial licensed tool to auto-generate C++ classes, including data and serialization/deserialization, based on an XML schema, then I strongly recommend [GSOAP](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2). It is easy to use, compliant to industry standards, and actively maintained.

See also http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDataBinding.htm

I was disappointed with many other C++ XML tools that promise full data bindings but will fail to process more extensive sets of WSDLs and schemas such as ONVIF. Having to retool an entire project was a pain. I know that GSOAP will do the job. A winner IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Not open source, but won't [XML Thunder](http://www.xmlthunder.com/) work for you?

Comment: It's C rather than C++ but worth a look. I can't see a download/buy/pricing link on their site though, can you?

Comment: Don't know much else about them other than they've been doing this a long time.  Good luck.