# Is it possible to generate a C++ class from a xsd using Qt (without the XSD tool)?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xsd, code-generation

I get several Datasets listed in a single xml File. I have to extract each dataset and do some operations depending on their values (not changing the content of the xml file).
So I have to parse that file.

With the .Net Framework I would simply use the XSD tool to generate a matching class avoiding to write a parser myself. Unfortunately that project has to be done using Qt and mingw and I'm not sure if there is similar tool.

Is it possible to (auto)generate a c++/qt class from xsd?

If it is: how?

Comment: Hmmm... just fount this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445905/xml-schema-to-c-classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question! You should not worry if Qt has such a feature. You can use [CodeSynthesisXSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) which is open source. The you can combine the generated classes to your Qt project.

Comment: CodeSynthesis XSD seems to be what I am looking for

Comment: While the answer does offer an alternative I find it to be not a proper answer. First of all one should look into CodeSynthesisXSD's licensing policy, which is different from what Qt has. This can potentially lead (depending on the Qt project that the OP is working on) to legal issues. Second of all this is an external dependency, which (again depending on the Qt project) may be something that is to be avoided (for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check `CodeSynthesis XSD`
see [this](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/)

Comment: Notice the GPL license.

Answer (score 0):

I think with [xmlpatterns module in qt](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406064734/doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtxmlpatterns.html)  it should be really easy and qt way to parse the xsd and make the corresponding qt c++ representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [xsd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) to generate C++ code. It goes with Visual Studio and `xsd /language` will show which languages do `xsd.exe` support which includes CPP also.

Comment: xsd.exe does not generate vanilla C++ (like C++03, C++11) but [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) - you can see this by looking in the generated header: `#using <mscorlib.dll`, `[assembly:SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction::RequestMinimum, SkipVerification=false)];` or `private: System::String^  receiverField;` is not what you'd expect in C++. My Question was for [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), not for [C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-cli/info). Unless you can force xsd exe to generate say C++11 code, xsd is not the tool.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm facing the same problem now. So, after all, you use ``CodeSynthesisXSD`` does it generate vanilla C++ code?

Comment: I don't remember if I actually used it to generate the production code but I remember using it.

Comment: Using CodeSynthesis also provides the same output which is C++/CLI, not vanilla C++. ``#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Data.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>`` include in the header file.