# Is there an equivalent of XSD2Code in native c++?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

In C#, I use XSD2Code in order to:

- generate automatically entities from XSD
- generate methods which serialize/deserialize XML stream in these entities

Does it exist in the native C++ world?

I am looking for libs which work on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Schema to C++ Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445905/xml-schema-to-c-classes)

Comment: also http://code.google.com/p/xplus-xsd2cpp/

Comment: `@Patrice` don't tell me! Fix your question instead!

Comment: Unfortunately, [xplus-xsd2cpp](http://code.google.com/p/xplus-xsd2cpp/) does not advertise support for Windows. As of the date of my comment, only Linux variants and Mac OS X are listed as supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

No, C++ has no such feature.

However, there are a plurality of *libraries* for C++ which provide everything you could possibly need. I am sure that at least several will exist to suit your XML needs (yuck!).

In particular, "*[CodeSynthesis XSD - XML Data Binding for C++](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/)*" looks promising.

<sup>I get 1,120,000 Google results for `xsd xml c++`.</sup>

Comment: One of those google results (in fact, the second after CodeSynthesis for me) is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/445905/85371