# C: How to create a XML file with the default format

Tags: c, xml, api, tinyxml

I'm beginner in `XML` and I have this information:

```
box1 -> name, colour, from

box2 -> name, weight

box3 -> name, colour, from, weight
```

and I want to make one `XML` file like this:

```
<boxName>name1
    <boxColour>colour1</boxColour>
    <boxFrom>from1</boxFrom>
</boxName>
<boxName>name2
    <boxColour>colour2</boxColour>
    <boxWeight>weight2</boxWeight>
</boxName>
<boxName>name3
    <boxColour>colour3</boxColour>
    <boxFrom>from3</boxFrom>
    <boxWeight>weight3</boxWeight>
</boxName>
```

I created my `XML` using `TinyXml` in this form:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlDeclaration* decl = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "");
doc.LinkEndChild( decl );
TiXmlElement* element = new TiXmlElement("boxName");
doc.LinkEndChild(element);
TiXmlText* text = new TiXmlText("name1");
element->LinkEndChild(text);
TiXmlElement* element2 = new TiXmlElement("boxColour");
TiXmlElement* element3 = new TiXmlElement("boxFrom");
TiXmlText* text2 = new TiXmlText("colour1");
TiXmlText* text3 = new TiXmlText(from1);
element->LinkEndChild(element2);
element->LinkEndChild(element3);
element2->LinkEndChild(text2);
element3->LinkEndChild(text3);
doc.SaveFile( "XML.xml" );
```

but the problem is that number of boxes is unknown and each box may have 1,2,3 or more child, but the format for each box and it's information is the same (as the above)

please help me to make the XML file

**I am coding in C / API**

Thanks

Update:

I can use a `for loop` just in this form:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    TiXmlElement* element2 = new TiXmlElement("element");
    TiXmlText* text2 = new TiXmlText("text");
    element->LinkEndChild(element2);
    element2->LinkEndChild(text2);
}
```

1: I can't say `If one box have weight then use <boxWeight> tag and add <boxWeight>weight2</boxWeight> if not don't have <boxWeight></boxWeight> tag`

2: I have the boxes Information's in a buffer in this form:

`box1  name:name1  coloure:  coloure1 from: from1` I don't know how to split the information (C/API)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is `How to create a XML file with the default format` / what should I do to solve my problem, I have some boxes, and I don't know how many box may be, and I want to make a xml file for them

Comment: Ever tried a `for` loop?

Comment: yes, but a loop that make for example 3 box with all information, I can't say `If the box have weight then <boxWeight>weight2</boxWeight> if not don't have this tag <boxWeight></boxWeight>`

Comment: @chaedrae the update to your question are actually two new questions. 1. Use another `if` statement. 2. look into how to parse C strings.

Comment: yes bus these are related questions, is it possible to write at the end of xml file?

Answer (score 1):

The standard practice I have seen in most places is to have a schema file (an XSD file) which states the acceptable format.

```
<xs:element name="boxName" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Colour" type="xs:myStringType"  minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="From" type="xs:date"  minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

The `minOccurs` means "this element is optional"

The `maxOccurs="unbounded"` means "as many as necessary"

You would then have checks in place to ensure that any XML conforms to this schema.

You could then easily use a `for` loop:

```
// pseudo-code
for each box,
    if colour variable exists, create and add colour element
    if weight variable exists, create and add weight element
    if from variable exists, create and add from element
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm codding in C/C++,  I didn't understand how and where to use this schema file, sorry if it's a bad the question, this is the first time that I'm creating xml file

Comment: @chaedrae I've edited the question slightly to add C/C++ tags, hopefully it will get more attention

Comment: thanks, should I create an xsd file before I write the program and then read it in the program?

Comment: Yes, usually the XSD file would exist outside your code, and you can convert it into C++ objects automatically, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445905/xml-schema-to-c-classes