# Generate XML Schema(.xsd) to C++ class

Tags: c++, xml-parsing

I'm new to C++ compare to my ex in using Java and C#. I often use xsd.exe in C#(a plugin in visual studio) to generate C# class from an XML schema

In java I use this command[image: In Java]

I have tried using several tools such as(XBEditor, WinLMX,...) to generate C++ class but the result is often different between them and It doesn't look like a C# or Java class but contain too many other information. I just want to ask what is the tool used the most in parsing .xsd to .cpp or In Cpp, this topic doesn't have much support.

Answer (score 0):

Using xsd.exe can also parse .xsd to C++ code by this command :

`xsd /language:CPP your.xsd /classes`.

It will produce your.h file.

Comment: I tried running this command and got the error: `Error: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, CppCodeProvider, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.`. In the documentation it says you need to run `SDKVars.bat` to set the paths properly but that bat file doesn't exist... Do you know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, unfortunately the files generated by this tool are not usable for me... I need them to work cross platform and this generates Windows specific C++/CLI files. Anyway for info on how to make it work see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658816/xsd-exe-does-not-seem-to-work-for-c-with-newer-versions-of-visual-studio